# Unexpected response code 500 for POST method Volley error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post, android-volley

I'm finding the following error with my request post method: **Unexpected response code 500 for POST method.**

It was working fine and then it just stopped working and started to display this error.

**this is my post method:**

```
private void postRequest(String empresa, String matricula, String foto, String data, String face) {
             RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
             String url="http://can't show the url";
             StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String response) {
                     //análise de dados json
                     try {
                         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                     }
                     catch (Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                       //  post_response_text.setText("POST DATA : unable to Parse Json");
                     }
                     Log.d("Response", response);
                 }
             }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // post_response_text.setText("Post Data : Response Failed");
                     Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                 }
             })
    {
                 
    @Override
                 protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                     Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     params.put("Id", "");
                     params.put("Empresa", empresa);
                     params.put("Matricula", matricula);
                     params.put("Foto", foto);
                     params.put("Data", data);
                     params.put("GPS", finalLatitude + "|" + finalLongitude);
                     params.put("idDispositivo", getIMEI());
                     params.put("arquivo", "");
                     params.put("face", face);
                     params.put("ip", getIP());
                     return params;
                 }
    
                 @Override
                 public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                     Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                     return params;
                 }
             };
             stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                     5000,
                     DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                     DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
             requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    
         }
```

I tried to do the post request on postman and it's working fine.

How i'm sending information on postman: [postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcfDD.png)